# Bug with hat placement with not-loaded avatar?

Tags: bug, status-declined, winter-bash

When I loaded the review page (in Stack Overflow, though I have no specific reason to think it is related) I got a weird hat in the upper left hand corner.

[image]

See the hat in the upper left hand corner?  That's belonging to user # [3651800](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3651800/matt-coubrough).  His profile page also has the hat in a ... weird ... location, but not *this* weird.

[image]

I'm guessing this is due to the not-loaded image for the avatar (adblock blocks Facebook avatars for me often)?  It also causes the toolbar notification to show his link unless I'm hovering over something else.  It also changes the location of the gray box to the upper left hand corner when I hover over the hat (and hovering over the white box does nothing).

It's definitely him (or any not-loaded avatar perhaps), once he fell off the last 6 reviewers it stopped appearing.

Comment: Do you happen to have Facebook blocked? That user does have a profile image, and I'm guessing you have an extension or something that is removing or hiding that element because it links to Facebook, so the when the script adds it, it doesn't go onto an actual, visible element.

Comment: Facebook is certainly the reason: Adblock for some reason blocks those images. I'm trying to point out the issue with the hat being misplaced when the image is not loaded, not the missing image.  I suppose if that's unavoidable from SO's point of view then don't worry about it, but I was thinking they might be able to avoid it (as I suspect a lot of people run adblock).

Comment: You run a browser plugin that removes things out of the page that we put there, causing our JS to do weird stuff because it has a reasonable expectation of that thing being there. How is that our bug?

Comment: If you're *only* blocking the HTTP request and not completely removing the element, it still works and [gives him a nose](http://i.stack.imgur.com/aKGcR.png).

Comment: @balpha I'm not intentionally blocking it: it's being blocked by adblock automatically (without me intentionally doing something).  My point is that probably a significant number of users run that script, so it may be behaving oddly for many users. But if that's not an issue (and I'm fine with that!) then ignore me.